# Using scipy.signal.convolve2d to implement vectorized scipy.signal.convolve 1d?

Tags: scipy, signal-processing, convolution

Support i have two same length list of 1d vectors `d1, d2` with same shape.

My goal is to obtain the new list `r[i] = np.convolve(d1[i], d2[i], mode='same')`.

And my questions is how can i construct some 2d matrix `m1, m2` such that, i can benefit from `scipy.signal.convolve2d` to get `r` in one function call ?

I'm also interested in vectorize this result `l1[i] = np.convolve(d1[i], d1[i-1], mode='same')`, can i generate a 2d matrix `n1` to get `l1` in one function call of `scipy.signal.convolve2d` ?

Comment: What about `r = scipy.signal.convolve2d(np.array(l1), np.array(l2), mode="same")` where `l1` and `l2` are your lists of 1d vectors?

Comment: It won’t be the same, 2D convolution is bi-directional, what my need is single directional